# Can a Flash-based CFGRID render basic HTML in the cells?

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid, cfgridcolumn

(I'm **very** new to both Flex and CF -- more a .NET/ExtJS guy, so I'm a duck out of water.)

I'm tweaking someone else's CFGRID code. It uses Flash format--HTML isn't an option since it would require redesigning the entire interface around the grid.

Tha data I want to put in the grid have some *very* simple HTML elements-- `<sub>`, `<sup>`, and HTML entities like `&deg;`. I can imagine `<i>` or `<b>` might be there in the future.

How can I tell a particular CFGRIDCOLUMN to render its *contents* as HTML?

I've heard this is possible, but Google is not my friend tonight.

Stuck with CF7 for a few more weeks, so if there are any CF8/CF9-specific solutions, please let me know those as well, but that won't help my immediate need.

Comment: supported tags of fx 1.5

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/15/flex_docs_en/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=part3_as.htm

I'd try finding possible methods to be called from cf, if i remember well there are some, can't find them now. You could write AS method and convert text before showing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't, sorry.